# Operations on array indices

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I am new to app development and need help with some simple logic.  I have an array of float values. The calculation involves two entries in the array but needs to be repeated until every possible combination of entries have been calculated.

ie x = (2* entry2) -entry1

Obviously my only way of referencing these entries is with index numbers. So I would assume x=(2*array[id+1])-array[id]

However my sequence would need to step the second array id down, and once 0 is reached increment both array IDs +1 and repeat the process until the first ID has reached the maximum ID number. 
Or am I going about this the wrong way.  Any help would be appreciated.

Currently I have RFArray and I want to populate IMProdArray so my code would be:

```
IMProdArray+=[2*(RFArray[2])-(RFArray[1])]
```

But I need a loop to repeat this for all possible combinations of ID numbers in the array.

So If I had 4 entries in the Array:
    IMProdArray+=[2*(RFArray[3])-(RFArray[2])]
    IMProdArray+=[2*(RFArray[3])-(RFArray[1])]
    IMProdArray+=[2*(RFArray[3])-(RFArray[0])]
    IMProdArray+=[2*(RFArray[2])-(RFArray[1])]
    IMProdArray+=[2*(RFArray[2])-(RFArray[0])]
    IMProdArray+=[2*(RFArray[1])-(RFArray[0])]

And then the reverse the order for all ID numbers:

```
IMProdArray+=[2*(RFArray[2])-(RFArray[3])]
IMProdArray+=[2*(RFArray[1])-(RFArray[3])]  
IMProdArray+=[2*(RFArray[0])-(RFArray[3])]
IMProdArray+=[2*(RFArray[1])-(RFArray[2])]
IMProdArray+=[2*(RFArray[0])-(RFArray[2])]
IMProdArray+=[2*(RFArray[0])-(RFArray[1])]
```

Thanks,

SamP

Comment: Happy to help, but want to make sure I give you the right code.  Can you edit your post and include an example of a couple of cycles of the entries and answers?

Comment: Please condense the question to just what you are asking for rather than the back story.

Answer (score 1):

For example, define an Array extension with a function that returns all the pairwise combinations of its elements, then map over the pairs with the calculation you wish to perform:

```
extension Array {

    func pairs() -> [(T, T)] {

        // you can take this nested func out for reuse
        func reverseIndexPairs(var count n: Int) -> [(Int, Int)] {
            assert(n >= 0)
            var ps = [(Int, Int)]()
            for e1 in stride(from: n-1, through: 0, by: -1) {
                n--
                for e2 in stride(from: n-1, through: 0, by: -1) {
                    ps.append((e1, e2))
                }
            }
            return ps
        }

        return reverseIndexPairs(count: self.count).map {
            (self[$0.0], self[$0.1])
        }
    }
}

let arr: [Double] = [0,1,2,3]

println("test order: ")
for e in [0,1,2,3].pairs() {
    println(e)
}

println("\nresult array <- 2 * x - y:")
let resultArray = arr.pairs().map { x, y in 2 * x - y }
for e in resultArray {
    println(e)
}

println("\nresult array <- 2 * y - x:")
let resultReverse = arr.pairs().map { x, y in 2 * y - x }
for e in resultReverse {
    println(e)
}
```

If I understood you right, you want the pairs to be in the reverse order, so the code above prints:

```
test order: 
(3, 2)
(3, 1)
(3, 0)
(2, 1)
(2, 0)
(1, 0)

result array <- 2 * x - y:
4.0
5.0
6.0
3.0
4.0
2.0

result array <- 2 * y - x:
1.0
-1.0
-3.0
0.0
-2.0
-1.0
```